# Сессия для не авторизованных и БД для авторизованных корзина Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel, сессия

У меня есть контроллер для корзины:

```
class BasketController extends Controller
{
    public function addCart(Request $request, $id){
      $product = Product::find($id);
      $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : NULL;
      $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
      $cart->add($product, $product->id);

      $request = Session::put('cart', $cart);

      Session::flash('add-product', $product->name);

      return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

Для примера взял только функцию, добавляющую товар в коризну, так же это все работает через отдельный класс Cart:

```
public function add($item, $id){
      $storedItem = [
        'qty' => 0,
        'id' => $item->id,
        'prod_url' => $item->url,
        'code_cat' => $item->category->code,
        'url_cat' => $item->category->url,
        'name' => $item->name,
        'cost' => $item->price,
        'price' => $item->price,
        'img' => $item->cardImage->path
      ];
      if($this->items){
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
          $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
      }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['cost'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
```

Тоже для примера взял только добавление.

Пока это все работает на сессиях. Опыта в Laravel не много, как лучше сделать следующий механизм:
Если пользователь не авторизован, то сохранять товары корзины в сессии, если же авторизован, то в БД?
Куда писать логику добавления в БД? Здесь же? Куда присать проверки типа: if(Auth::check()) то брать код  для БД, else , код для сессии?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Опишу на примере. Допустим у нас будет контроллер CartController
Там у нас будет два методы добавления. Один будет для бд второй - сессии.

Для бд:

```
public function addToCartDB($product, $qty, Cart $cart)
{
   $cart->product_id = $product->id;
   $cart->qty =$qty;
   ///и тут дальше...
   $cart->save();
}
```

Для сессии так же

```
public function addToCartSession($product, $qty)
{
   $cart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart[$product->id] = array(
        "name" => $product->name,
        "qty" => $qty,
    );

    Session::put('cart', $cart);
    Session::flash('success','Сохранено');
}
```

Ну и так дальше... думаю логику можно уловить?

Хотя я больше люблю через сессии всегда.

Comment: То есть роуты отдельные для БД и Сессии? Я что то думал все в одной функции, но какая то проверка должна быть на авторизацию пользователя.
На счет сессии, мне тоже она больше нравится, БД не засоряется, но вообще видел на многих сайтах через пару лет зайдешь в корзине все осталось, вполне удобно.

Comment: Да, лучше отдельные. Если авторизован - то ссылка на один роут, а если нет - на другой. Не забывайте о том, что такие роуты лучше делать API

Comment: Не так давно пользуюсь Laravel. Что за роуты API? Вот пример роута на добавление товара в корзину:
`Route::get('/basket-add/{id}', [BasketController::class, 'addCart'])->name('basket-add');`.
Это ведь не API, а Web?
Здесь почему то так написали: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/swift/laravel+8+api+routes
Толком инфы об API роутах не нашел, где можно подробнее почитать для чего они и как ими пользоваться?

Comment: да, загуглите про api.php

Comment: Единственное, что нашел в Laravel связанное с API - это Resourses? Т.е. мне надо сделать ресурс и через него всю логику корзины написать?

Comment: Нет. Можете почитать эту статью https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial